# Does PetClinic Example break Single Responsibility Principle

Tags: spring, oop, design-patterns, single-responsibility-principle

I as just curious plus also to better understand SRP, petclinic spring mvc example has one big Clinic inetraface which has methods for owner, pet and visit.

SRP on the other hand says "that one class(here the implementation class of Clinic/ inetrface itself) should do **one task defined**. So, then Clinic inetrface should have been broken into 3 interafces? Or I got the SPR/petclinic example wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are referring to the SpringSource [PetClinic example](http://static.springsource.org/docs/petclinic.html); the docs says:

> The high-level business/persistence API for PetClinic is the org.springframework.samples.petclinic.Clinic interface. Each persistence strategy in PetClinic is a different implementation of the Clinic interface.

and it is also mentioned that:

> Since the PetClinic application is all about database access and there is very little business logic in the application outside of that, there is no separation of the primary Business and Persistence Layer API's. While this design technique should not be used for an application with more complex business logic, it is acceptable here because all of the non-persistence related business rules have been implemented in business objects and have not leaked into the Persistence Layer. The most important facet of the design is that the Business and Persistence Layers are COMPLETELY independent of the Presentation Layer.

finally according to its [original definition](http://www.butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod), SRP says that

> A class should have one, and only one, reason to change.

so in a way the design is coherent with SRP, as the Clinic interface encapsulates the persistence API of the application, and its implementation will change only because of underlying changes in the persistence strategy/technology used. On the other hand, as it is mentioned, this is a pretty simple example, and you're right guessing that in a more complex application the persistence/data-access layer will most likely be split by entity: usually you end up having one DAO per major entity, so in the PetClinic something like OwnerDAO, PetDAO, VisitDAO.